# Extract by mask/copy raster a RGBA (4bands) raster results in a greyscale image in photoshop discarding all RGB composite info

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, multi-band

I used a polygon Shapefile to extract by mask (ArcGIS) the sea area from a RGBA (4 bands aerophoto) raster. The Extract by Mask caused up-sampling from 16 bit (my raster's initial pixel depth) to 32 bit so I used "copy raster" to down sample the raster to 16 bit and entered the "0" value for nodata.

The problem is that when I open the new raster in photoshop the band composition is lost and the RGBA raster opens as a grey scale raster in photoshop. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

I used composite bands operation and made a new composition but nothing changed. Is it possible photoshop is not working with nodata values?